# How to add an iOS Observer on AVPlayer in nativescript plugin?

Tags: ios, avplayer, nativescript

I am developing a nativescript app that stream a webRadio, and for that I  have used the plugin nativescript-audio.
This plugin do the job on Android, but on the iOS part, I have replaced the AVAudioPlayer by AVPlayer because AVAudioPlayer doesn't manage web streaming. Actually, I try to understand how to manage the variables and events observer to be notified when an event is trigged or a value involved.

I tried to be notified when player has reached the end of a media :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserverSelectorNameObject(
  _this,
  NSSelectorFromString("playerDidFinishPlaying"),
  AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
  null);



TNSPlayer.playerDidFinishPlaying = function (args) {
  if (this._completeCallback) this._completeCallback();
};
```

But this code crashed during execution because it doesn't find the method playerDidFinishPlaying.

I also wanted to be notified on the `AVAudioPlayer.currentItem.status` to know when the player involved to `AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay`

I tried to adopt swift example to nativescript format but no success.

Could you help me to resolve my problems?
Thanks

Comment: Up.Someone to help me?

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?